# How to join two files

Tags: text-processing, join

I want to join two files, and I must use the command join.
This is first file
file1.txt

```
SUBJID  SEX DTHHRDY
GTEX-1117F  2   4
GTEX-111CU  1   0
GTEX-111FC  1   1
GTEX-1122O  2   4
```

This is the second file
file2.txt

```
GTEX-1117F-003-a
GTEX-1117F-003-b
GTEX-111CU-0011-a
GTEX-111FC-0011
GTEX-1122O-0045-a
GTEX-1122O-0045-b
```

As you can see file 1 match with file 2 in column 1. Besides, I have to join these two fields filtering column 2 and 3 in file 1. For column 2 I have to take all values 2, for column 3 all values that are 4.

Output required

```
Sample  SEX DTHHRDY
GTEX-1117F-003-a    2   4
GTEX-1117F-003-b    2   4
GTEX-1122O-0045-a   2   4
GTEX-1122O-0045-b   2   4
```

GTEX-1117F is related with GTEX-1117F-003-a because the two first lines are the same, the difference is -003-a but you can cut this and you will see that they are related. I tried `join -1 1 -1 1 file1.txt file2.txt`,
but I got this message "join: incompatible join fields 1, 2". Furthermore, I created two new files with this `awk '{if ($2 == "2") print $1,2,3}'` , so I have 12 data, but now I don't know how to join with file2.txt. Also, I must use `join` command

Comment: Why must you use `join`?

Comment: I edited the input, I didn't notice that. And I need to use join because my statement says that.

Comment: If this is homework, show what you have tried with `join` and we can help you out. Don't expect us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
head -n 1 file1.txt
join <(paste -d" " <(cut -d- -f1-2 file2.txt) file2.txt | sort) \
     <(tail -n +2 file1.txt | sort) \
| cut -d" " -f2- \
| awk '$2 == 2 && $3 == 4' \
| column -t
```

```
SUBJID  SEX DTHHRDY
GTEX-1117F-003-a   2  4
GTEX-1117F-003-b   2  4
GTEX-1122O-0045-a  2  4
GTEX-1122O-0045-b  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `join` is that the join fields must be identical. So you have to massage file2.txt to have a field that can be matched exactly from file1.txt

Also, the data must be sorted.

[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)s are extremely useful when working with `join`.

Comment: I made it. I created a file that I called second that has the data of GTEX, 2, 1. I have 12 data in this file. Then, I created an another file based with data of file 2 where I cut the character after - (e.g. -003-a), I joined the two files.
I mean: join second.txt another.txt
I got 332 data, like this:
```
GTEX-12ZZX 2 1
GTEX-12ZZX 2 1
GTEX-12ZZX 2 1
GTEX-12ZZX 2 1
```